# PureLayout Center with Offset

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've been trying to center the following UIView to be 70 pixels above the absolute center of the phone. I would like to use PureLayout so that the constraint will change when I use split screen on an iPad or rotate the screen. Here is my current code:

```
self.checkBall.frame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width/2 - self.checkBall.frame.width/2 + 70
self.checkBall.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height/2 - self.checkBall.frame.height/2 - 70
```

Comment: Note on your current code: Your description sounds like you just want to move the view up, but your code is shifting it both up and to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You're using PureLayout?

```
self.checkBall.autoAlignAxis(.vertical, toSameAxisOf: self.view)
self.checkBall.autoAlignAxis(.horizontal, toSameAxisOf: self.view, withOffset: -70.0)
```